# Are Excel's localized function names documented

Tags: excel, localization

Is there a reference of Excel's localized function names?

For example, the function "SUM" is "SOMME" in French and "SUMA" in Spanish.

Is there an exhaustive documentation somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a list of English/French/German function names [here](http://www.software.maninweb.de/news/261/279/Comparison-and-function-list-of-Excel-2010-2007-and-2003/d,news_details.html), or a comprehensive list of functions in 14 different languages

- Brazilian Portuguese (português
  brasileiro)
- Czech (čeština)
- Danish   (dansk)
- Dutch (nederlands)
- Finnish   (suomi)
- French (français)
- German   (deutsch)
- Hungarian (magyar)
- Italian   (italiano)
- Norwegian (norsk)
- Polish   (język polski)
- Portuguese (português)
- Spanish (español)
- Swedish (svenska)

  [here](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/).

**EDIT**

I also have a set of Russian function names, though I'm not aware of any other translation sites with that set of data.

I'm always interested in other language lists if you manage to track any down.

**EDIT 2**

For some information about other localization issues, Ron de Bruin, Kirill Lapin and Hector Miguel Orozco Diaz have this [excellent page](http://www.rondebruin.nl/international.htm) that mentions a host of further localization differences.

**EDIT 3**

Russian function names are included in the Russian language files for PHPExcel. The full text is too big to post here, but You can find it in the [source repository](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/71420#1602164).

Comment: as my website has been mentionned (software.maninweb.de, thanks), just want to inform you, that I have released an Online Excel Formula translator here: http://translator.excel-ticker.de/ Currently 16 languages are included and you can translate both single or combined excel formulas. Regards :-)

Comment: No documentation about some xls 2010 functions such as SUMIF.

Comment: is there any way to change it to english having other language? they are crazy that they localized function names.

Comment: Not so crazy.... Excel is written to be used by people for whom English may not be their native language, and who may not even speak English, or whose native language may not even use a Latin alphabet

Comment: unfortunately some of the links are dead. @MarkBaker but Excel for non-Latin languages still use English function names. It seems only European languages have localized names

Comment: @FlashThunder just install a [language pack](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and change Excel's language to English. There's also an official [Excel functions translator](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-functions-translator-f262d0c0-991c-485b-89b6-32cc8d326889) that translates the whole expression or gives you the function list in all the supported languages

Comment: As per today, The link is unfortunately broken

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

A list of English function names is available from Microsoft here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188

If you change `en-us` in this URL to another language short code such as `de-de`, `fr-fr` or `it-it`, the page will be displayed in that language. All the Excel functions will also be shown in the selected language. For example, Italian is here:

https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/office/funzioni-di-excel-in-ordine-alfabetico-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188

A list of language short codes (technically 'BCP 47 codes', I believe) used by Microsoft is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oe376/6c085406-a698-4e12-9d4d-c3b0ee3dbc4a

(Not all of these are necessarily supported by the page above.)